# Alignment issue?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, errors, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align the 2 equals signs and the minus sign at the beginning of each line of the following code, but no matter what I do, it won't work.

```
$C_{n}$  = $ \dfrac{1}{4\pi{i}} $ $ \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} x^2e^{ix({1-n})}\ dx $ $ - \dfrac{1}{4\pi{i}} $ $ \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} x^2e^{{-ix}({1+n})}\ dx $ 

\bigskip $  = \dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\Bigg[ \bigg[\dfrac {x^2ie^{-i(n-1)x}}{n-1} \bigg]_{-\pi}^\pi -  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} \dfrac{2xie^{-i(n-1)x}}{n-1} \ dx \Bigg] $  

\bigskip $  - \dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\Bigg[ \bigg[\dfrac {x^2ie^{-i(n+1)x}}{n+1} \bigg]_{-\pi}^\pi -  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} \dfrac {2xie^{-i(n+1)x}} {n+1} \ dx \Bigg] $
```

Answer (score 3):

There are probably better ways to do this, by completely restructuring your answer in terms of an `align` environment (see below), but this answer has the least "impact" on your original attempt.  In essence, I add a `\phantom` to the beginning of the 2nd and 3rd lines.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$C_{n}$  = $ \dfrac{1}{4\pi{i}} $ $ \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} x^2e^{ix({1-n})}\ dx $ $ - \dfrac{1}{4\pi{i}} $ $ \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} x^2e^{{-ix}({1+n})}\ dx $ 

\bigskip $\phantom{C_{n}}  = \dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\Bigg[ \bigg[\dfrac {x^2ie^{-i(n-1)x}}{n-1} \bigg]_{-\pi}^\pi -  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} \dfrac{2xie^{-i(n-1)x}}{n-1} \ dx \Bigg] $  

\bigskip $\phantom{C_{n}}  - \dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\Bigg[ \bigg[\dfrac {x^2ie^{-i(n+1)x}}{n+1} \bigg]_{-\pi}^\pi -  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} \dfrac {2xie^{-i(n+1)x}} {n+1} \ dx \Bigg] $
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is a way to do it with `align`:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
C_{n} &=  \dfrac{1}{4\pi{i}}  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} x^2e^{ix({1-n})}\ dx  - \dfrac{1}{4\pi{i}}  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} x^2e^{{-ix}({1+n})}\ dx 
\\[2ex]
&= \dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\Bigg[ \bigg[\dfrac {x^2ie^{-i(n-1)x}}{n-1} \bigg]_{-\pi}^\pi -  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} \dfrac{2xie^{-i(n-1)x}}{n-1} \ dx \Bigg]  
\\[2ex]
&- \dfrac{1}{4\pi i}\Bigg[ \bigg[\dfrac {x^2ie^{-i(n+1)x}}{n+1} \bigg]_{-\pi}^\pi -  \displaystyle\int^\pi_{-\pi} \dfrac {2xie^{-i(n+1)x}} {n+1} \ dx \Bigg]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```